# JavaScript recursion base case

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm sorry I know this is probably not a smart question but it's driving me crazy. Given this recursive function, why is 1 not returned all the time? I mean, eventually the exponent will get to 0!

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Are you asking why this works (calculates a power...) or why it DOESN'T work (which is wrong since it does work...)

Comment: print the values and you will see what happens at each step of the recursion

Answer (score 7):

The best way to understand is to walk through the code. Let's say you do power(2,3).

What does that do?

```
2 * power(2,2) 
//Which expands to
2 * 2 * power(2,1)
//Which expands to
2 * 2 * 2 * power(2,0)
//Which expands to 
2 * 2 * 2 * 1
```

Answer (score 2):

When 1 is returned, it is not returned to the original function call, but just the most recent function call. Every time the `power` function calls itself, it puts a new invocation of itself on the stack. So for instance if we call `power(2, 1)`, that will call `power(2, 0)`. `power(2, 0)` will return its value of `1` to where it was called in `power(2, 1)`. Then `power(2, 1)` will return `base * power(base, exponent - 1);` which is `base * 1` which is `2`.

Answer (score 2):

This may best be understood by contrasting your recursive `power` function with a very similar function that *does* always return the value `1`.

```
function one(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return one(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

Notice that the only difference between your `power` function and `one` is that the the recursive call to `one` *is* the value being returned in the recursive case.

In your `power` function, the value being returned is `base` multiplied with the value of the recursive call.  Thus each recursive call to `power` contributes to the value ultimately being returned by the initial call; whereas, only the final call to `one` (when `exponent` is `0`) contributes to the returned value.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we call `power(2, 5)` [i.e. with `base`=2 and `exponent`=5].
It will evaluate in the following way:

```
power(2, 5) = ...
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 5)`. Is `exponent==0`? No it isn't (it's 5). Then we return `base*power(base, exponent-1)`, which actually means `2*power(2,4)`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * ?
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 4)`. Is `exponent==0`? No it isn't (it's 4). Then we return `base*power(base, exponent-1)`, which actually means `2*power(2,3)`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * (2 * power(2, 3))
            = 2 * (2 * ?)
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 3)`. Is `exponent==0`? No it isn't (it's 3). Then we return `base*power(base, exponent-1)`, which actually means `2*power(2,2)`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * (2 * power(2, 3))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 2)))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * ?))
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 2)`. Is `exponent==0`? No it isn't (it's 2). Then we return `base*power(base, exponent-1)`, which actually means `2*power(2,1)`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * (2 * power(2, 3))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 2)))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 1))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * ?)))
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 1)`. Is `exponent==0`? No it isn't (it's 1). Then we return `base*power(base, exponent-1)`, which actually means `2*power(2,0)`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * (2 * power(2, 3))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 2)))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 1))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 0)))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * ?))))
```

Hmmm... Let's calculate `power(2, 0)`. Is `exponent==0`? Yes, it is! Then we return `1`.

```
power(2, 5) = 2 * power(2, 4)
            = 2 * (2 * power(2, 3))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 2)))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 1))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * power(2, 0)))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * 1))))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * 2)))
            = 2 * (2 * (2 * 4))
            = 2 * (2 * 8)
            = 2 * 16
            = 32
```

Post Scriptum: You should understand that `return <something>` specifies result value of *the innermost (i.e. the latest)* function call (not the outermost, i.e. the oldest).

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the result of multiplying the base by itself a certain number of times, which is how exponents work. Because `base` is being multiplied by `power(base, exponent - 1)` (and `power(base, exponent - 1)` itself is not being returned), each iteration where `exponent` is not 0 essentially adds another multiplication of the base onto the result.

As an aside, this is not a very good power function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why is it not a good power function? The way the code is written or just using recursion in general here?

Comment: @ccnixon Here's a resource I found on how to write a more efficient power function (in C, but the same principles apply): http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/