# Can't grasp the exponent function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I can't seem to grasp why the exponent function,

```
function power(base, expon) {
    var result = 1;
    for(var count = 0; count < expon; count++)
        result *= base;
    return result;
};
```

works. In particular, I am clueless why the value of the operation "return result" is not, e.g., "2", if the arguments for the function are power(2, 3), making the operation "result *= base", equal to "1 *= 2" (=2).

The 'for' statement seems to play no role whatsoever here... it increments the variable 'count' until it reaches "'expon' - 1", i.e. "2" if the arguments for the function are power(2, 3), and then does nothing with it.

What am I missing and interpreting incorrectly?

Comment: The role of the `for` loop is to execute the line `result *= base;`. See [how `for` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Recursive version of this iterative question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029430/javascript-recursion-base-case/32029498#32029498

Comment: @Teemu: Can you elaborate? I am drawing a blank here. The statement "result *= base" seems to have nothing to do with the 'for' statement above it(both commands have no variables in common...), just like the 'for' statement has nothing to do with the statement 'var result = 1', above it. How does it execute it?

Comment: Well, it might look like it wouldn't, but it has. Please read the documentation I've linked. Tordek's answer also explains your issue well.

Comment: _"if the arguments for the function are power(2, 3), and then does
 nothing with it."_ ? `power(2,3)` appear to return `8` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` statement takes a body. It can either be...

```
for (...) {
    statement();
}
```

or

```
for (...)
    statement();
```

When the body of the `for` contains a single statement, the braces are optional.

In this case, the line `result *= base` is executed `count` times.

Answer (score 0):

The operation `result *= base;` is inside the for (implicit) "block". It's executed in a loop. That's why it works.

If you'd properly indent your code it would be easier to see this.

Comment: @Teemu - You'd be right if they would indent incorrectly (which they did). Had the indentation been indicative of the fact that the multiplication statement happens inside the loop, they'd see *The 'for' statement **plays a role***

Comment: Umh... Indentation in JS is ignored. That would only have been a clue, but without basic understanding of how `for` loops work, OP can't even indent the code properly.

Comment: @Teemu Yes I know it means nothing in JS, and yes I realize OP doesn't understand that `for` without curlies isn't the same as `for` with a semi-colon, but if an automatic indentation was being used (even the one in the embeded JS editor here on SO), it WOULD help see "something is going on there". Anyway, that's not the essence of my answer, it's just a tip for general coding standards.

Comment: Not actually related, but I've never seen any automatic indention in SO code blocks, is there really something available?

Comment: @Teemu OF COURSE! the inline snippet tool does indentation. I suppose by your comment that you don't know it. That's a big shame... always use it when you can. Detached code fragments are far less useful then runable code.

Comment: Oh, you mean _Stack snippets_? Yes, I'm aware of them, but in the OP there's an inline code block only, that doesn't have any automatic indentation. If it really has, please give me a link to "help" or sth.

Comment: @Teemu :-) I know.. I just said that *even the one in the embeded JS editor here on SO*, not that the OP used it...